# Jquery .ajax get request with Odata

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, odata

I am facing the following problem, I am trying to build a small application to search within the Odata dataset from the KVK (dutch chamber of commerce) to retrieve data based on file numbers, ZIP codes or tradenames.

My ajax code looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: urls,
        error: function(){console.log('FAILED!')},
        headers: 
        {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "ovio-api-key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

the URL would like like this:

https://overheid.io/api/kvk?&filters[postcode]=3553BA&callback=jQuery110208921047365292907_1432134770039&_=1432134770040

The error I am getting:

[image]

The part I do not understand, when I try the exact same URL in a web rest client such as chrome's advanced rest client the result is exactly what I want:

[image]

Comment: The response is in the wrong format. You would need it to be JSONP, not JSON, to consume it with javascript in a browser cross-domain. Your only option is to use the api in such a way that it returns JSONP (if that is even possible,) or don't send the request with the client's browser.

Comment: Unfortunantly for this assignment I am required to do this explicitly client side. When I change the datatype from jsonp to json I am facing the issue of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." Is there any work around for this issue ?

Comment: Just fixed it, Thanks to your reply i had a close look and saw that the ajax request was missing a GET type, added this and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by changing the code to:

```
                $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urls,
        error: function(){console.log('Gefaald!')},
        headers: 
        {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "ovio-api-key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

just had to add the 'GET' type.